# How to use window.open method

Tags: internet-explorer, toolbar

I know by `window.open` method we can force IE to open new browser window without any tool bar by using this following code.

`window.open ("","mywindow","status=1,toolbar=0");`

But, what I want is... I've a login form & what i need to do is, when ever user enter his/her login id & password & press submit button the next what ever page will open(after successfully login) in that browser's tool bar should not appear there.

Can any body help me with the exact code which needed to produce this thing.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `window.open` is the `URL`, so you just pass the requested url as the first parameter and execute window.open after the user is logged in.
Using the same format to hide the `toolbar`, the only problem is there is nothing stopping the user or a web page opening another window that would default again to having the toolbar decoration.